# Filter through an array of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I have a list given to me :

```
NameList = [
    {"key1": a, "key2": b, "key3": c},
    {"key1": d, "key3": e, "key2": f},
    {"key3": g, "key1": h, "key2": i},
    {"key2": j, "key1": k, "key3": l},
]
```

I am trying to create a new array with just the values of each individual 'key3'.

I have done:

`NameList =` above

```
finalarray=[]
for item in NameList:
    for item2 in item:
          if item2[0] == 'key3':
              finalarray.append(item2[0])
```

I get a syntax error.
when I did

```
for item in NameList:
    for item2 in item:
          finalarray.append[item2]
```

I received

```
finalarray = [ 'key1', 'key2', 'key3' ...]
```

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

Comment: You should have been using [`.items()`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/dictionary/items) like *`for k,v in item.items():` `if k=='key3': finalarray.append(v)`*. However, this loop is unnecessary since you can do **`if 'key3' in item: finalarray.append(item['key3'])`**. Using [list comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension) like in [Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75844305/6146136) is more efficient than appending on a loop though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason to loop through the dictionaries and test each key against `"key3"`. You can just index for the key (assuming each dictionary has that key). This can be done in one line:

```
NameList = [
    {"key1": 'a', "key2": 'b', "key3": 'c'},
    {"key1": 'd', "key3": 'e', "key2": 'f'},
    {"key3": 'g', "key1": 'h', "key2": 'i'},
    {"key2": 'j', "key1": 'k', "key3": 'l'},
]


finalarray = [d['key3'] for d in NameList]
# ['c', 'e', 'g', 'l']
```

If it's possible the key isn't in the dictionary, you can filter this dicts out:

```
finalarray = [d['key3'] for d in NameList if 'key3' in d]
```